# How to create c# object for Grid Sorting paramter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have sort in the grid.

When the grid send select request to the server, it is sending like {name: "asc"}

next time when sorting with created by, the parameter is {createdBy : "asc"}

Can you please tell me how to created a object in c# for this sortby parameter.So that this object is converted to c# object in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public enum SortDirection
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
}

public class SortOption
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public SortDirection Direction { get; set; }

    public SortOption(string fieldName, SortDirection direction)
    {
        FieldName = fieldName;
        Direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
var mySortOption = new SortOption("name", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: Sorry i can't hardcode the "FieldName" in this class because the property name is dynamically coming from the grid